# Need a callback for html2canvas function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html2canvas

When I click on save button, I want first to save the images using html2canvas (this takes 1 to 3 seconds sometimes) after this is done I need a callback to run the other functions.

Also my save button on click is redirecting to another page and there is using this json generated in this function:

```
$('#save').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#slideshow li img').attr('src').indexOf('placehold.it') >= 0 && $('#slideshow').is(':visible')){
        alert('Please add a image to Slideshow or remove it to continue.');
    } else {
        html2canvas($('.bg'), {
            allowTaint:false,
            useCORS:true,
            logging:true,
            proxy:''+builderURL+'proxy.php',
        }).then(function(canvas) {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            $.post(''+builderURL+'thumb.php',{
                template_thumb: dataURL,
                template_id: TEMPLATE_ID
            });
        });
        // if i run functions from here, i lose html2canvas bec this takes 1-2secounds and my save function is redirecting on click
    }
    alert('if image is generated continue from here')
    $('#DataState, #DataTemplate').val('');
    createJSON();
    createHTMLJSON();
    createCSS();        
});
```

If I run it like now I get redirected with no image.
Where to add a callback? Tryied after html2canvas and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call an asynchronous request. In JQuery you can use .ajax for this. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
After the function is executed, the callbackfunction will be executed.

Comment: $.post is just a wrapper around $.ajax. You should give an example of how to add the actual callback to the call.